# Is reusing BitmapFonts possible in GDX?

Tags: libgdx, fonts, memory-efficiency

I'm loading multiple labels (100+) with different font types (max 10), but they have different sizes.

As I read the code and did the research, it's not possible to 'reuse' the font.

For instance, I have 5 labels made with GILL_SANS font but these labels must have different scales (font scales).

Should I really make 5 different `BitmapFont` objects for different scales (AND LOAD THESE TERRIBLE GRAPHICS AGAIN AND AGAIN) or is there any way to optimize this (without loading `.fnt` and `.png` again)?

One load takes 2mbs of RAM (huge png) + ~2ms which is unacceptable for 100 labels.

**Edit**
I've check that. Label caches fonts so you can scale the same font and use setFontScale() on each label. But what about TextField?

Comment: One thing could be just load those letter that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=24124&sid=afb7ff8255e632d2dfcc9383c8001603

The best way to achieve this is to copy the whole `Textfield` class, add some variables like:

`float fontScaleX, fontScaleY;`

and scale and unscale them in `draw()`.

Comment: 404 :c. Would've loved that read